# Australian or NZ bands like Mountain Goats, Neutral Milk Hotel, etc.?

Tags: rock, similar-artists, indie, folk

I am looking for Australian or New Zealand bands like Mountain Goats, Neutral Milk Hotel, etc.? This may not exist.

I am also interested in any bands with a similar sound from other languages or regions, such as Asia, Central/South American or Continental Europe.

I would describe the sound I am after as "indie lo-fi folk rock"

I would also be interested in other non-american/non-UK suggestions. Maybe French or Latin American?

Comment: @Chris Sunami I appreciate the input on this old question, as it remains a question of interest to me. In this case however, Daniel Johnston, Iron & Wine and Tunng sound nothing like Mountain Goats or Neutral Milk Hotel.

Comment: I can only imagine that my description is inadequate because Sugarcubes and Gotye are pure pop. Similar sounding artists, though American, would be AJJ and Ghost Mice.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest :

- [Cloud Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Control), an indie rock band from the Blue Mountains (Australia).
- [Georgia Fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_Fair), a folk rock band from Sydney.
- [Boy & Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_%26_Bear), folk rock band from Sydney.

Check this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zs3Q_HlUEfk) for more ideas.

### On lo-fi style

The [Hawk Moth Records](https://hawkmothrecordco.bandcamp.com/) label has published a [compilation](https://hawkmothrecordco.bandcamp.com/album/hawk-moth-records-shed-sessions-vol-1) with various Australian folk artists. As they say in the description:

> We wanted to capture everyone raw and un-produced and just right.

So it might be closer to lo-fi style.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. they are all good bands. i would say that they are missing the 'lo-fi' sound. can you think of any bands with a 'lo-fi' element?

Comment: @jakethedog The 'lo-fi' part wasn't in you original question... I will check that part.

Comment: was trying to avoid misleading genre labels

Comment: @jakethedog, you still don't like the additions I've made on my answer?

Comment: finally had a chance to listen. definitely closer to the mark, thanks. i won't accept it as an answer though as none of them really come close, though they are in the right ballpark. you seem pretty good at this, so if you are looking to make more suggestions, another element that strikes me as absent in the previously suggested music is 'sadness', if you know what i mean.

Comment: @jakethedog You can still vote this up without accepting it.